# Unserialize cart data not working Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm save my cart products as unserialized data from my cart session.

$order = new Order();

```
$order->cart = serialize($cart);
$order->code = strtoupper(str_random(15));
$order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$order->save();
```

now i need to unserialize the data to use it in my blade file, this is the function i'm using

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->findOrFail($order->id);

        $orders->transform(function($order, $key){

            $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);

            return $order;

        });

        dd($orders);
```

I'm getting this error

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Order::transform()

what seems to be the problem? and how can i unserialize my data;

any ideas ???

Comment: The `transform` method belongs to a collection, you may instead use [casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Comment: Show you model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With findOrFail you retrieve just one instance of model, not a collection.

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->findOrFail($order->id);
```

Also what is $order->id you have your order model?

So

```
$order->load('user');

$order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
```

Or do you want a collection then your code will work like this

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->get();

$orders->transform(function($order, $key) {
    $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);

    return $order;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about `unserialize`, it doesn't even get there. The problem seems to be related to an undefined method you are trying to use (`$orders->transform`).

Can you please provide the code in your Order class? Did you define the `transform` method there?

EDIT:

by using `serialize` you are kinda' missing the point of a relational database and the datatypes inherent in your database engine. Doing this makes data in your database non-portable, difficult to read, and can complicate queries.

Also, many tests prove that `json_encode` is faster than `serialize`.